# Interrupt 10h 0x4F05 in assembly: Why does the operation fail?

Tags: assembly, x86

```
mov ax, 0x4F05 
xor bh, bh 
mov dx, 1022
int 0x10
```

When I call function 4F05h of int 10h, this one reveals an error in the operation.

ah is 1 which means there is an error according to the documentation

I activated the video mode: 8107h with 4F02

I don't understand why it gives me an error

I tried to change the value of dx or change the video mode, put another one, I also searched on google but nothing conclusive

Comment: Does it work with `dx=0`? Note you need to consult the mode info about window granularity so you know what you can pass in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First; there are 2 display windows and you need to tell it which window you're changing. This is done by setting `bl` to either 0 ("window A") or 1 ("window B").

Note 1: Ralph Brown's Interrupt List is wrong - it says `bl` is an output parameter when it's an input parameter. Use (the appropriate version of) the actual VBE spec as a reference.

Second; different video cards have different window granularity, but it's often 64 KiB. The value in `dx` is in "units of window granularity"; which means your `mov dx,1022` is possibly like "set the window to start at byte offset `1022*64*1024 = 66977792` in video memory". This needs to be somewhere in the frame buffer; and assuming (see note 2) you're using "1280 x 1024 with 8-bit indexed color" the maximum sane value for `dx` would be `(1280*1024*1 - 1) / window_granularity`, or, with 64 KiB window granularity the highest value for `dx` would be 19 (giving access to offsets from 0x130000 to 0x13FFFF in the frame buffer, with the byte at offset 0x13FFFF being the last byte that exists in the frame buffer).

Note 2: The fixed mode numbers from early versions of the VBE standard were deprecated in VBE 2.0 (in 1994), so "mode 0x107" could (in theory) be any video mode.

Of course all of this means that (for slightly portable code) you can't just use hard-coded values for anything. You have to search for the mode you want (using the list of mode numbers from Function 0 and the details of each mode from Function 1), and you have to use the "WinGranularity" field from the video mode info data structure obtained from Function 1 to calculate values for `dx`.